# Azure Management Service API gives deployment configuration in some Encrypted format

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, powershell-3.0

I am using this code to get the deployment configurations.

```
X509Store certificateStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
certificateStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
X509Certificate2Collection certs = certificateStore.Certificates.Find(
     X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, certThumb, false);
if (certs.Count == 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Couldn't find the certificate with thumbprint:" + certThumb);
    return;
}
certificateStore.Close();

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(
    new Uri("https://management.core.windows.net/" + subID +
            "/services/hostedservices/" + hostedServiceName +
            "/deploymentslots/" + deploymentType));
request.Method = "GET";
request.ClientCertificates.Add(certs[0]);
request.ContentType = "application/xml";
request.Headers.Add("x-ms-version", "2009-10-01");
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
    // Parse the web response.
    Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);

    // Display the raw response.
    Console.WriteLine("Deployment Details:");
    string deployment = reader.ReadToEnd();

    // Close the resources no longer needed.
    responseStream.Close();
}
```

But I am getting configuration in encrypted format.

But if run azure powershell it gives me the configuration in plain text.

```
$deployment = Get-AzureDeployment -ServiceName $serviceName -Slot $slot
$deployedConfig = $deployment.Configuration
```

Since I have to use service management API how can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the [expected behavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460804.aspx). REST API returns the data in `Base64` encoded format. Since Windows Azure PowerShell consumes the same REST API, they convert the data from Base64 format and present it in humanly readable format. This is what you would also need to do.

So in your code you would do something like this:

```
string clearText = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(
                      Convert.FromBase64String(reader.ReadToEnd()));
```

Comment: Thanks Gaurav. highly Appreciated for your quick reply.